# Style output of an jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array containing a number of statements/quotes but I would like to add some custom HTML to help style each quote when they are displayed.

In the below code I have demonstrated what I'd like to do but at the moment the actual HTML tags are output as strings. How do I get them to render as HTML so I can style them with CSS?

Here's a working fiddle showing what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/tawasnng/1/

```
// Random testimonials headlines = new Array('Food was amazing and the drinks well-priced. We’ll be back soon!<span class="boom">Test</span>', "Bad", "Ugly", "Random Headline");    var randomNumberBefore = 4;

   function randomNumberByRange (range, number) {
      var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range-1));
      if(r >= number)r++;
      return r;    }

   $(document).on('click','.nextquote' , function() {

      var randomNumber = randomNumberByRange( headlines.length, randomNumberBefore);
      randomNumberBefore = randomNumber;
      var nextHeadline = headlines[randomNumber];

      $(".quote").text(nextHeadline);

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) in order to make it output as HTML. Replace the following:

```
$(".quote").text(nextHeadline);
```

With:

```
$(".quote").html('<span class="headline">' + nextHeadline + '</span>');
```

And try giving something for the `.headline` class!